# How do i load information from a textfile in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to use the ()Load method. I have done it without a problem on PHP but now I want to do the same on ASP.net.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            $("#test").load("footershop.txt")
        });
    });
</script>

<section class="shop">
    <footer>
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/klader.jpg")" alt="klader">
    <div id="test" >
        <p class="shoptext">text</p>
    </div><br />
    <button id="btn">Mejla oss</button>
    </footer>
</section>
```

Here is my code in ASP.net. I put the "footershop.txt" in the App_Data folder. It does not show up. Where should I put the textfile in ASP?

Comment: you can't load directly a txt file by jquery in client side. you have to call a controller action method and read the text file using File.ReadAllText at the server side and return the string response which you can show at client side.

Comment: Ohh I see. I thought it was more simple, thanks for the help!

Comment: posted a workaround for you . let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

you can use $.ajax instead of `load` to show the textfile content in the div. The txt file should be in the same directory path for the below code to work else you have to specify the actual path at the `url` property

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
            url : "footershop.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
                $("#test").html(data);
            }
         });

        });
    });
</script>
```

you should be testing it from a server not from local system as there might access issues in local to read the txt file.